# I'm trying to get an estimate for the accuracy of a decision tree, Why do i get a TypeError?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

## training data (20%)
data = pd.read_csv("train.csv", usecols=[1,2,9])
X_train = pd.read_csv("train.csv", usecols=[2,9])
y_train = pd.read_csv("train.csv", usecols=[1])

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=6)
dt.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_predict = dt.predict(X_test)

accuracy = dt(y_test, y_predict)
```

i get "TypeError: 'DecisionTreeClassifier' object is not callable" even though i (mostly followed a datacamp tutorial).

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dt(...)` is attempting to "call" `dt` which you can't do because `dt` is not a function. You need a function that calculates accuracy from true and predicted labels.

Try something like this

```
def calculate_accuracy(y_true, y_predicted):
    num_correct = sum(map(lambda t, p: t==p, y_true, y_predicted))
    return num_correct / len(y_true)
```

```
accuracy = calculate_accuracy(y_test, y_predict)
```

**EDIT:**
The more beginner friendly version of my `calculate_accuracy()` would look like

```
def calculate_accuracy(y_true, y_predicted):
    num_correct = 0
    for i in range(len(y_true)):
        if (y_true[i] == y_predicted[i]):
            num_correct = num_correct + 1
    return num_correct / len(y_true)
```

Comment: Do you have any advice on how I could do that? edit: ive realised i was supposed to be using accuracy_score but im going to do more research on my problem

Comment: Updated @Javonne